# Same values are getting added to db multiple times

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, hibernate

// LoginDAO, logic to save UI values into DB... new values are getting added and old values are replaced

```
System.out.println("In Vendor registration i.e LoginDAO class::::::::::"+vendorRegistration.getVid()+""+""+vendorRegistration.getFirstName());
                Session session = getSession();                               
                session.beginTransaction();                                                //begin transaction for the session.
                Query query = session.createQuery("UPDATE VendorRegistration set firstName =:firstname,lastName =:lastname,Email =:email,password =:password,Vid =:vid "); 

                query.setParameter("firstname",vendorRegistration.getFirstName());
                query.setParameter("lastname",vendorRegistration.getLastName());
                query.setParameter("email",vendorRegistration.getEmail());
                query.setParameter("password",vendorRegistration.getPassword());
                query.setParameter("vid",vendorRegistration.getVid());              

                int user = query.executeUpdate();

                 session.save(vendorRegistration);
                 System.out.println("user values are ::::::::::::::::::"+user);
                session.getTransaction().commit();                            //here transaction complete with commit the data in db. 
                session.close();



// Controller class

@RequestMapping(value = {"/signup"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveRegAction(@ModelAttribute("signup") @Validated VendorRegistration vendorRegistration, Model model,HttpSession session,BindingResult bindingResult) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("the object is:" + model);
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors())
        {
            logger.info("user details===========" +vendorRegistration.getFirstName()+""+vendorRegistration.getLastName()+""+vendorRegistration.getVid()+""+vendorRegistration.getEmail()+""+vendorRegistration.getPassword());
            logger.info("Returning home.jsp page"); 

            model.addAttribute("vendor", new VendorRegistration()); 
            return "signup";
        }
        loginService.saveNewUser(vendorRegistration);
        session.setAttribute("vendorRegistration", vendorRegistration);

        logger.info("in registration page........... save register action");
        return "vendorLogin";
```

//values are saving multiple times retaining old values and saving new values into DB

![this is the issue with DB][1]][1]

//pojo class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VendorRegistration")
public class VendorRegistration  {


    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)  
    private long id;


    @Column(name = "VID")
    private String vid;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    @Email(message="Please Enter Valid Email ID")
    private String email;

    @Column(name ="PASSWORD")
    private String password;
//getters and setters
```

Comment: First why are you executing a query AND are saving the entity? Remove your query and execution of is. You only should use `session.save(your-entity)`. Also you shouldn't add a `new VendorRegistration()` to the model in case of errors, it is already added don't add it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong/flawed in your code. First your controller, it has a wrong method signature.

First fix the method signature, the `BindingResult` **must** directly follow the method argument it applies to, in your case the `@ModelAttribute` annotated element.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/signup"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveRegAction(@ModelAttribute("signup") @Validated VendorRegistration vendorRegistration, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model,HttpSession session,) throws IOException { ... }
```

The issue you have with your database is due to the implementation of your service/dao method. You first execute an update query and finally insert it. So what happens is first everything is updated and after that a new record is inserted. You should only have `session.save` nothing more and nothing less in your method.

```
Session session = getSession();                               
session.beginTransaction();                                                 

session.save(vendorRegistration);
session.getTransaction().commit();                           
session.close();
```

This remainder of your code is however still flawed, as it might lead to starvation of the connection pool in case of errors/exceptions. You should use a `try/catch/finally` in your code. (Or even better let Spring do that for you by using Spring managed transactions).

```
final Session session = getSession();
try {
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(vendorRegistration);
    session.getTransaction().commit();                           
} catch (Exception e) {
    session.getTransaction().rollback();
}  finally {       
    session.close();
}
```

You basically need something like that for each and every method that works with the session. If you don't, your `Session` might hang around and use a connection from your connection pool. If that happens enouhg your application will die or start to crawl.

Better is to use Spring managed transactions.

```
@Transactional
public saveNewUser(VendorRegistration vendorRegistration) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(vendorRegistration);
}
```

Spring now manages the session and transaction for you.

**Pro Tip:** Don't use plain hibernate but use JPA and use Spring Data JPA with it. Then you only need this.

```
interface VendorRegistrationRepository extends JpaRepository<Long, VendorRegistration> {}
```

No implementation, only an interface and everything is managed for you.

Comment: accepted... if possible can you brief abt ur pro-tip.... about that interface u mentioned

Comment: That is all explained in the Spring Data JPA guide. You just extend an interface and you have all the crud (save, update etc) you need without needing to implement anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in

```
Query query = session.createQuery("UPDATE VendorRegistration set firstName =:firstname,lastName =:lastname,Email =:email,password =:password,Vid =:vid ");
```

You have not added where clause. So all records are getting updated.

Comment: How can I answer that :p. Maybe he is trying to do update operation for existing users and insert operation for new users. But he is trying to do it with same query.